# R xml xpathApply for TEI

Tags: xml, r

I'have a xml-tei-file.xml look like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="parser.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
   <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
      </fileDesc>
      <revisionDesc>
         <change>
            <name/>
            <date/>
         </change>
      </revisionDesc>
   </teiHeader>
   <text>
      <body>
         <div><p><date when="1715-01-07">Du 7e  Janvier.</date> Un ambassadeur extraordinaire du roi.</p></div> 
        <div><p><date when="1715-12">Dudit mois de décembre</date> Quelque temps avant la fin du mois</p></div>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

I would like to get information when="1715-*" 
Si I have tried

```
library(XML) 
doc<-xmlParse("xml-tei-file.xml")

> getNodeSet(doc, "//date[@when]")
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

or

```
> unlist(xpathApply(doc, '//date', xmlValue))
NULL
```

How to get date node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, use `xmlGetAttr`:

```
unlist(xpathApply(doc, '//date', xmlGetAttr,"when"))
[1] "1715-01-07" "1715-12"
```

Comment: >unlist(xpathApply(doc, '//date',xmlGetAttr,"when"))
NULL

Comment: I am using `htmlParse` since your xml is not well formatted. Try `doc <- htmlPasre(url)`

Comment: An alternative to `xpathApply` or `getNodeSet` is to use `[`, like `when = doc["//date[@when]"]` or `when = doc["//date[@when]/text()"]` followed by `sapply(when, xmlValue)` If there's only a single element that satisfies the criterion then use `[[`,  `doc[['//date[@when="1715-12"]']]` or `doc[['string(//date[@when="1715-12"])']]`.

Comment: @delaye It looks like this answer solved your problem. If it is the case, it would benefit everyone if you marked it as accepted. By doing so, you get reputation, the answerer gets reputation and people passing by who would like to help know that your problem has been resolved already.

Comment: Et voilà, sorry I had not yet understood how it worked ... now it's DONE :-) !