# attribute value extraction in XML using R

Tags: html, xml, r

I am not sure how to do this

```
library(XML)
hp <- htmlParse('<li><div class="subtle">Culture and Values</div> <span class="notranslate gdBars sm " title="5.0"> <span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><</li>')
```

I want to extract "title" value which "5.0" in the above example using R code.

thanks   Is there any way that I can specify that I want to retrive only those "title" values from "span" where "Culture and Values" appears in "div"?

Comment: This is essentially the same as this link: [R xml xpathApply for TEI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934454/r-xml-xpathapply-for-tei) as in `xpathApply(hp,"//span",xmlGetAttr,"title")[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply

Comment: `xpathSApply(hp, "//span[@class='notranslate gdBars sm ']", xmlAttrs)[2]` also works

Comment: also `xpathSApply(hp, "//span[@class='notranslate gdBars sm ']/@title")` (my XPath is far too rusty). That one provides the attribute value directly w/o indexing.

Comment: Seems conceptually more like you're extracting an element than iterating over a set, so `hp[["number(//span/@title)"]]` unless title is actually a character string, then `hp[["string(//span/@title)"]]`

Comment: thanks 
Is there any way that I can specify that I want to retrive only those "title" values where "Culture and Values" appears in "div"?