# R: XML: XPATH: Get title from html tag

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I have an html file with thousands of entries with the following structure.

```
<li class="li1">
  <div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">    
      <div class="div3">
        <a class="a1">
            <strong class="strong1">name</strong>
            <div class="div4">2ndname</div>
        </a>
        <small class="small1">
            <a href="URL" class="a2" title="INFO I WANT!">
                <div class="div5">time</div>
            </a>
        </small>
      </div>
      <p class="p1">Main info</p>



        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I'm using R to extract the information with the CSS package. Here's what works untill now.

```
doc <- htmlParse("myfile")
name <- cssApply(doc, ".li1>.div1>.div2>.div3>.a1>.strong1", cssCharacter)
2ndname <- cssApply(doc, ".li1>.div1>.div2>.div3>.a1>.strong1", cssCharacter)
```

I want to get the title of the  title so I'm using XML directly. I've tried:

```
uh<-xpathApply(doc, "//li[@class='li1']/div[@class='div1']/div[@class='div2']/div[@class='div3']/small[@class='small1']/a[@class='a2']", xmlGetAttr, "title")
```

But I only get NULL. Some help would be really apreciated. I've read [attribute value extraction in XML using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400478/attribute-value-extraction-in-xml-using-r?lq=1) and several others but I cannot find what I'm doing wrong.
Thank again!

Comment: `uh` contains `"INFO I WANT!"`(in a list of length 1) here, so I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: could havind more than one item cause the problem? I'm checking again if I've mislabeled any tag

Comment: So the example I gave does work.. the real one doesn't, not even with a single one. I've checked and rechecked. Exact same syntax, only the names of the classes change..

Comment: if there a reason you can't submit the HTML excerpt that's actually causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I misunderstood the structure of the data in the file. The exammple written here worked with the parser but the real data didn't. I was missing a level.